# How do I convert from a Json Byte Array for AMQP in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, kotlin, rabbitmq, mqtt, spring-amqp

[Following this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54995261/206466), I have this code

```
@Bean
open fun messageConverter(om: ObjectMapper): MessageConverter {
    return Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(om)
}

@Bean
open fun rabbitListenerContainerFactory(cf: ConnectionFactory, mc: MessageConverter ): SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory {
    val factory = SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory()
    factory.setConnectionFactory(cf)
    factory.setMessageConverter(mc)
    return factory
}

@Bean
open fun builder(): Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer {
    return Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer {
        it.modules(JavaTimeModule(), KotlinModule())
        it.featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
    }
}
```

but I'm getting this exception

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message
Endpoint handler details:
Method [public phg.entity.monitor.Foley phg.event.monitor.Provisioning.save(phg.entity.monitor.Foley)]
Bean [phg.event.monitor.Provisioning@2212e291]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:193) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:127) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1547) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1473) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1461) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1456) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1405) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:870) [spring-rabbit-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:854) [spring-rabbit-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:78) [spring-rabbit-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1137) [spring-rabbit-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1043) [spring-rabbit-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [[B] to [phg.entity.monitor.Foley] for GenericMessage [payload=byte[263], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=foley.new, amqp_receivedExchange=amq.topic, x-mqtt-publish-qos=1, x-mqtt-dup=false, amqp_deliveryTag=1, amqp_consumerQueue=foley.new, amqp_redelivered=false, id=c7fade5a-d803-166a-fe71-0a4f8abb8c4e, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-9bkLtT_xhvQACuHqvx_izQ, timestamp=1551886588001}]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PayloadArgumentResolver.java:144) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:117) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:147) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:49) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:190) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

stepping through the code before I notice that it's using the `GenericMessageConverter` and that there isn't a `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According your stack trace there is nothing in the Listener Container to do with your incoming JSON. So, it happens as just *pass through* with `byte[]` as a pyalod. What you end up is just an attempt to convert that `byte[]` to the expected type on your `@RabbitListener` method. For that purpose, when you don't have a JSON information to convert on the listener container level, you need to configure a `DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory` with desired `MappingJackson2MessageConverter`. It can be achieve with the `RabbitListenerConfigurer`:

```
    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory myHandlerMethodFactory() {
        DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory factory = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
        factory.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
        return factory;
    }


    @Override
    public void configureRabbitListeners(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
        registrar.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(myHandlerMethodFactory());
    }
```

That `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` can be configured as a bean for your custom `ObjectMapper` injection.

Comment: %$#@! https://stackoverflow.com/q/55093859/206466 fix one problem in the conversion, somehow end up with another very similar problem